# Gstreamer save camera video input to file returns empty file

Tags: gstreamer, video-capture, gst-launch

I'm trying to save the video input (it can also be frame by frame) from a camera, whose input I can display like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I want to save this video to a file, either in video format or frame by frame. So I try to run

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi
```

But my video.avi file is empty. What am I doing wrong? I am a beginner in GStreamer and I can't find useful information online so I can't figure out what each part of that pipeline is doing.

**EDIT**

Running with verbose I get this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, encoding=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, encoding=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
[INFO]  bitstreamMode 1, chromaInterleave 0, mapType 0, tiled2LinearEnable 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstImxVpuDecoder:imxvpudecoder0.GstPad:sink: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstImxVpuDecoder:imxvpudecoder0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)jpeg, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)0/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)jpeg, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)0/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)jpeg, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)0/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad1: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)jpeg, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)0/1
```

Comment: Could you run your pipe with `-v` parameter (verbose), and share the output here? `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi -v`

Comment: `/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)640, height=(int)480` shows `rtpjpegdepay` sees framerate as 0, are you sure about your source?

Comment: Well if the first command shows me the output of the camera on screen can I not safely assume that my source is right?

Comment: Yes, in this case we have a problem in the pipe. Can you try again this time replacing `decodebin` element with `jpegdec`.

Comment: It won't allow it. I get this: 
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "jpegdec"

Comment: Ok. Maybe your system cannot write raw avi file. Let's try encoding it with h264.
`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi` Seems like you have a system that supports openmax, maybe you can use `omxh264enc` instead of `x264enc` too.

Comment: the following command should work : `gst-launch-1.0 -ev udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi
`

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler when using x264enc I get "WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc" " and I get the same with omxh264enc. Where did you see that my system supports openmax?

Comment: @vk_gst when I run that command the video.avi file is created but empty.

Comment: How are you exiting the recording pipeline? Is it using Ctrl+C?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you typed the port with one fewer 0. I've corrected it and now it saves the file but when I try to play it with Ubuntu's video player or with VLC it won't work. VLC says: Codec not supported:
VLC could not decode the format "    " (No description for this codec)

Comment: Because you are writing raw video data to the AVI. Not all players support this. They usually expect a compression format.

Comment: So how can I write it to disk with some compression format? And are we not specifying the compression format with "encoding=JPEG"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could eventually write the stream of images using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! matroskamux ! filesink location=video.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

*"encoding=JPEG"* just specifies jpeg at that stage of the pipeline, but that is decoded by decodebin later, resulting in uncompressed, raw video.

You can check what encoders your gstreamer install supports with

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep enc
```

This also lists audio encoders. Probably you have to install additional gstreamer packages to get any or more encoders, like gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad or gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly (this package contains x264enc).

Then try the pipeline from @Alper again:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 ! application/x-rtp,encoding=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay \
! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install anything on this system.